# Multi-tenant Authorization in .NET Core 2.0: How To

Tags: .net, authentication, authorization, identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to set up multi tenant in .NET Core.  The basic idea is this:

- Use JWT for APIs
- Allow users to log in with services like Azure AD, Google, Facebook, etc
- Utilize Identity to allow users to log in with a site account

Anyone logging in with a 3rd party provider (Azure AD, Google, etc) will need to "register" for the first time.  Their Google Account will then be linked with a user account.  JWT tokens will also be mapped against a user account with specific permissions.

My inital attempt was to do something like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
   sharedOptions.DefaultScheme  =cookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddGoogle(optoins =>  Configuration.Bind("Google", options)) 
            .AddAzureAd(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
            .AddCookie();
```

The problem is that now I have multiple challenenge and authentication schemes in place, so my plan was to remove the default schemes and provide a way for the user to select what scheme they want to use.

What I did  is subclass `AuthenticationService` and override `AuthenticateAsync`, `ChallengeAsync`, and `SignInAsync`.  Authenticate and Challenege will re-direct to a page where the user will select their authentication preference.  Their choice is then stored in a cookie and used in subsequent calls to Authenticate and Challenege. Things are working so far, except now when `SignInAsync` runs there are no handlers that are registered.

At this stage, I am wondering if my approach to solving the problem is even correct: It seems like the startup should have registered the handlers I need.  I am sure there is a way for me to register the handlers based on the user's selection, but I am wondering if this is even correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through Microsoft's identity documentation, it appears that in order to get their examples to work as written, it's required to use identity.  The calls to `AddIdentity` and `AddDefaultTokenProviders` configure default  The following code will more-or-less do as I requested (save for JWT)

```
 //configure identity
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            //configure other providers
            var authSection = Configuration.GetSection("Authentication");

             var authBuilder=services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddGoogle(options =>  authSection.Bind("GooglePlus", options))
            .AddAzureAd(options => authSection.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

**Here's what the docs say:**

*Note:* The call to `AddIdentity` configures the default scheme settings. The `AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme)` overload sets the `DefaultScheme` property; and, the `AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions)` overload sets only the properties you explicitly set. Either of these overloads should only be called once when adding multiple authentication providers. Subsequent calls to it have the potential of overriding any previously configured `AuthenticationOptions` properties.